# Android Firebase Datasnapshot - a null object error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to check user data, and I get an error saying I pass a null object:

In the class:

```
FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseUser currentUser;
DatabaseReference ref;
```

on the onCreate:

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
```

After user signed in:

```
currentUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
```

And then:

```
   ref.child(currentUser.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String isAuthorized = ds.child("authorized").getValue().toString(); //the error says this is null
                        whichActivity(isAuthorized);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

[This is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4JVz.png)

Does anyone know how this error can be fixed? Thanks for responders.

Comment: just make sure `currentUser.getUid()` has some data within the reference or Instead of `@NonNull` make it nullable and check for safety

Comment: The error I get is: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference. I guess it says the object under the child "authorized" is null but I do not know why it happens. Any idea? And thank you for your respond.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `ds.child("authorized").getValue()` is returning null.  That can happen if there is no child named "authorized" in the snapshot.  If you are not certain that "authorized" is present, you should check it first before using it.

```
DataSnapshot authorized = ds.child("authorized");
if (authorized.exists()) {
    String isAuthorized = authorized.getValue().toString();
    whichActivity(isAuthorized);
}
```

Comment: Please see the image of my database I attached. I do have a child named "authorized". Why else could this happen? And thanks for your answer.

Comment: Well, we can't see the value you're passing for the UID, so that screenshot doesn't tell the whole story. I suggest editing the question to remove all doubt that your query fully matches your database.

Comment: Also we can't see what `ref` points to, so we don't really have an idea at all where you're fetching data.

Comment: I changed it by your advice. please check